# PC freezes before GRUB menu during boot, but works when cancelling boot menu options

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub

I recently installed Fedora 35 as a dual boot alongside Windows 11 and didn't like the default GRUB UI, so I installed a GRUB theme from gnome-looks.
The theme generally worked, but just before the GRUB menu, an error poped up for a second saying:

`error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:257:file '/EFI/fedora/fonts/unicode.pf2' not found`

I've read on [fedora project's discussion site](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/grub2-fonts-unicode-pf2-not-found-error-before-grub-menu-appears/33290/7) that copying `/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2` into `/boot/grub2/fonts/` fixes the error, but for me it broke the PC boot.

Now when booting, the PC shows the info about pressing a button for boot options and after it disappears it hangs indefinitely with the manufacturer logo. But when I hit the button to see the boot options and hit cancel to proceed with the normal boot procedure, GRUB shows up and everything boots as normal.

I'd appreciate any help with this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for a quick reply!

I managed to fix the issue with the use of live USB stick with the same version of Fedora I installed.

1. I Booted into the live USB,
2. created a mounting point: `mkdir /media/fedora`,
3. mounted the PC disk partition with my Linux installation: `mount /dev/<sda-or-nvme-partition> /media/fedora`,
4. overwrote the contents of `/media/fedora/root/etc/grub.d/.` with `/etc/grub.d/*` from the live USB stick,
5. removed any themes installed in `/media/fedora/usr/share/grub/themes`,
6. removed the `GRUB_THEME` entry from `/media/fedora/etc/default/grub`,
7. updated the `boot` files by running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` (command specific for Fedora),
8. and rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another machine, and the disk isn't encrypted, you should be able to remove the hard disk from your machine. Plug it into a USB-to-SATA adapter. Navigate to the partition and follow the directions you discovered on the Fedora website.